# Best practice for retrieving many images from Parse?

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I have an app which is photo-based, and had a ton of large-scaled resolution images on Parse.  I currently have my app set up to grab these images from Parse with a query, and storing each photo into an UIImage array with a loop, and then displaying these photos in a UICollectionView.

It works great, if we are pulling less than 10 photos from Parse.  However, if I am retrieving, say 20 photos, when I scroll down my UICollectonView after the photos have been loaded, around the 18th or so photo, my app will crash, and Xcodes console will output "Received memory warning".

What is the best practice for retrieving a large amount of large sized photos from Parse?  (If you are displaying them in a UICollectionView)

Comment: Have you considered using Parse's PFImageView?  It lets you set a source image and then will load image as soon as it can.

Comment: 1) lower res, 2) lower size (as @mark suggests), 3) only fetch content that needs to be visible, release content that ceases to be visible.  #1 and #2 can be done on the fly, slowing the fetch but saving space and bookkeeping on the server.  #3 slows the app, requiring more fetches generally.  Trading speed for space is part of the profession you've chosen.

Comment: This is an app that requires high quality images (real estate appraisal app).  Im going with the thumbail solution provided my Mark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would download only the thumbnails. You can even do this using lazy loading (http://www.theappguruz.com/blog/ios-lazy-loading-images) if so inclined.

When the image is clicked on and you want to see it full size, then you download the full size image :)
Set a limit on how many images you want to retain in memory, and use a [queue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queue_(abstract_data_type)) to decide when to store/get rid of the old images.

Comment: How do you download thumbnails?  Can you pull large images from Parse as a thumbnail?

Comment: Not as far as I know - you should save images as both full size and thumbnail size